# FuelUX Wizard - Allow direct selection of steps further down the process

Tags: wizard, fuelux

I've used the FuelUX Wizard on a form where people submit some data and we wanted to break it up into logical steps. It works really well.

Now I'm working on the edit version of the same form which is working fine, but as the steps already have the data loaded, I want the user to be able to jump straight to step X to tweak the bit they need to edit, rather than having to click next X times to get there.

I'm going to carry on working on this myself, but wondered if anyone else has already done this and can clue me into how to approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the first step when the page loads is simply to apply the class "complete" to each of the li elements and the class "badge-success" to each of the badges.

Then you need to stop it removing those classes for steps 4 to 6 when you click on step 3.

I hooked into the "changed" event and things were happening in the right order when I logged stuff to the console, but the "stepclicked" method seems to be being called twice, the second time after my "changed" stuff thereby undoing my good work.

Well I don't want to stack hacking the FuelUX Wizard code itself or we'll never be able to upgrade it so I came up with this nasty hack which will suffice until such time as the FuelUX code may be modified to allow this to be done more elegantly.

```
//KEEP ALL THE STEPS MARKED AS COMPLETE
$("#JetWizard").on("changed", function() {
    window["tid_wizard_steps_all_complete_count"] = 0;
    window["tid_wizard_steps_all_complete"] = setInterval(function() { jetKeepAllStepsMarkedComplete(); }, 25);';
}
function jetKeepAllStepsMarkedComplete() {
    $("#JetWizard ul.steps").find("li").addClass("complete");
    $("#JetWizard ul.steps").find("span.badge").addClass("badge-success");
    window["tid_wizard_steps_all_complete_count"]++;
    if(window["tid_wizard_steps_all_complete_count"] >= 20) {
        clearInterval(window["tid_wizard_steps_all_complete"]);
    }
}
```

It basically repeats itself twenty times in the first half a second after the step is clicked to ensure we keep things the way we want. Obviously you could use a longer interval and less repeats, but then you get an obvious "flash" in the steps.

Then I wanted to stop it actually navigating iof the fields on the current step have errors. So...

```
//HANDLE CLICKING ON STEPS TO GO BACK & FORTH
$("#JetWizard ul.steps li.complete").on("click", function() {
    if(jetDoLiveValidationOnVisibleFields() === false) {
        alert ("The form has errors");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old thread but I still have to ask this. How can I reset the "changed" event back to original state when the form was finish editing? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, here is some code you can run to allow clicking on all steps, not just completed ones:

```
var $wizard = $('#MyWizard').wizard();
var wizard = $wizard.data('wizard');
$wizard.off('click', 'li.complete');
$wizard.on('click', 'li', $.proxy(wizard.stepclicked, wizard));
```

You may then have some CSS styling to override to make it look like everything's clickable.

This is also being tracked at https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/175 as a feature request to make this easier to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. that works functionally, but like you said the styling still needs attention. I came up with this answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965109/fuelux-wizard-allow-direct-selection-of-steps-further-down-the-process/16979087#16979087

...yesterday (couldn't post due to lack of reputation) which focuses more on the styling and actually makes the functionality side of things work too as the LIs etc. have the right classes. It's a bit of a hack really, but it does get the job done so I'm running with that until there's something smoother done in Fuel UX itself

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on the accepted answer, but if anybody runs into the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stepclicked' of undefined", just replace

```
var wizard = $wizard.data('wizard');
```

for

```
var wizard = $wizard.data('fu.wizard');
```

and make sure you have

```
data-initialize="wizard"
```

In your wizard markup.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
//Initialize you wizard
$('#myWizard').wizard();

//Enable the steps except the actived one
var steps = $('.steps-container').find('li');
$.each(steps, function(i, val) {
  if (!steps.eq(i).hasClass('active')) {
    steps.eq(i).addClass('complete');
  }
});

// Add an event listener when change step, to enable other steps again
$('#myWizard').on('changed.fu.wizard', function (evt, data) {
   var steps = $('.steps-container').find('li');
   $.each(steps, function(i, val) {
      if (!steps.eq(i).hasClass('active')) {
       steps.eq(i).addClass('complete');
      }
   });
});
```